# Find the domain of $\frac{1}{\cos^2(\theta)+\cos(θ)}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

So I've gone back to school after a few years of being away.  Just got a calculus assignment and I'm blanking completely.  The problem I'm struggling with is:

Find the domain of $S(\theta)=\frac{1}{\cos^{2} \theta + \cos \theta}$

I know the answer is $(\frac{\pi}{2} < \theta-2 \pi n < \pi, n \in \mathbb{Z})$, but I don't remember how to get there and Google is not being helpful.  I'm not looking for a full rundown, but maybe a hint or two to jog my memory would be good.

Comment: Did you mean to write $S(\theta) = \frac{1}{\cos^2\theta} + \cos\theta$ or $S(\theta) = \frac{1}{\cos^2\theta + \cos\theta}$?  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Ok, finally got it: $S(\theta)=\frac{1}{\cos^{2} \theta + \cos \theta}$ is the correct function.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(\theta) = \cos(\theta)^2 + \cos(\theta)$.

Since we are considering $1/f(\theta)$ and we don't want this to be infinity, we require that $f(\theta) \neq 0$.

We know that $\cos(\theta) = 0$ whenever $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2} + n \pi$.

So $\cos(\theta)^2 + \cos(\theta) = 0 + 0 = 0$

We also know that $\cos(\theta) = -1$ whenever $\theta = \pi + 2n\pi$.

So $\cos(\theta)^2 + \cos(\theta) = (-1)^2 - 1 = 1 - 1 = 0$

These are the values at which $f(\theta) = 0$. At all other values the function is well defined.

Comment: Adding on to what Andrew said, you can factor $\cos(\theta)^2 + \cos(\theta)$ into $(\cos(\theta))(\cos(\theta) + 1)$ and we see that $f(\theta) = 0$ when $\cos(\theta)$ is $0$ or $-1$